# 14.10 High DPI cursor oddities

Tags: cursor

I've upgraded to 14.10 on my Retina MBP, and I've noticed some weirdness with my cursor display. On any application (firefox, term, etc...) it displays at the correct size. When I hover over any os spot (desktop, notification bar, unity panel, etc..) it's about a third the size. Any suggestions for consistent cursor size?

Comment: I've deleted my answer about `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 36` as *it didn't work anyway* and an unanswered question attracts more attention.

Comment: This seems to be a problem in 15.10 too.